# Upgrading to Java 8 / Spring 4, cannot start Tomcat because: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, sessionfactory

I'm taking a code base and upgrading to Java 8, which means also upgrading to Spring 4.  I cannot run the resultant executable, though, even though it compiles.  Instead I get this error at Tomcat startup:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '**org.hibernate.SessionFactory**' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

This worked fine before; what do I need to change?  I'd be grateful even for a "RTFM" if it came with pointers to the relevant manual section.

Comment: can you show us your persistence configuration ? One of your bean is expecting a hibernate SessionFactory to be injected but none can be found.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but here are the relevant snippets from my pom.xml:

javax.persistence.version>2.0.3</javax.persistence.version>
[...]
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
            </dependency>